# Horizontal Chart Axis in MS Excel / Word is in "Category Mode" by Default... Change to other unit?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, charts

[chart-axis-stuck-on-categories-format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLVxY.png)

I'm using MS Office 2010, at the moment.
When I create any linear chart, my horizontal axis displays "Category 1, Category 2, etc..."
I want it to be something like "10º, 20º, 30º, etc..." In other words, I want it in degree units with a minimum of 10º, a maximum of 90º and an interval of 10º.
Thank you in advance, and have a nice one all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the axis display (Category 1, 2 etc) so that it has a box around it then right click and choose Change Data. This will allow you to specify a range that you want to use for the titling that axis. You can change the range by clicking Edit. I attached a picture of what the window should look like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqoTX.jpg

Comment: Works! Thank you for sharing your knowledge and saving my time, Mr Rhodes.
It's very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The video below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8dzLXYAFVU&t=90s

explains granularly how to use the secondary axis in Excel.

Right-click on the axis, you want to edit.
Find "Axis Options", where you will be able to define the bounds and set the units (intervals).

This is for 2016, for 2010 should be analogical.

[image]